# imageView doesn't replace the previous drawable with the new one

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-drawable

```
ImageView coloring = findViewById(R.id.badge1);
coloring.setImageResource(R.drawable.coins);
```

when I set the image view drawable programmatically , it adds the new drawable but keep the previous one in the background [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avIkU.png)

I tried

```
coloring.setImageResource(0);
coloring.setImageDrawable(null);
```

but it still kept.

Comment: `src`and `background` are two different attributes . Just use one at a time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in layout.xml you set background to your imageView try this in layout.xml to your image

```
   android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

instead of

```
   android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

Comment: he said programmatically.

Comment: read the full question first then critic...he dint say where he set the 1st image...he said **when he replaces the first image** @JaydipKalkani

Comment: Yes I agreed with @SantanuSur. If he correctly sets image resource to android:src, then it will work when he update the image programatically. This is not the problem of the way he does programatically. This is because he set image at android:background in his xml.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani use some guessing power...ifhe knew the difference programatically..he would nt have posted the question

Comment: okay okay. Sorry @SantanuSur My mistake. I didn't have seen it.